# How to Extend PHPUnit in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am trying to extend the PHPUnit in Laravel, but I’ve faced a problem - application instance is not loaded. I'll do my best to explain my problem.

I want to implement `TestListener` interface and `TestListenerDefaultImplementation` trait to use PHPUnit Listener feature. But also I need to use my models in this listener.

As you can guess I cannot do this because Laravel’s `CreateApplication` trait is used only in a pair with its BasicTest. Thus the listener does not know anything about the application instance. How can I manage to do this with listeners?

My phpunit.xml file:

https://gist.github.com/andrewgorpenko/1a7d472ab4747f081c7da247261e29d1

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by *As you can guess I cannot do this because Laravel’s CreateApplication trait is used only in a pair with its BasicTest.*

Comment: I’ll clarify it more. You may know about the PHPUnit feature called “Test Listeners”. I’ve implemented them and they are working. BUT. These listeners cannot use application instance. Why? Because only TestCase uses CreateApplication trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an intended feature of the framework and what I did is a kind of "bad practice".